# Install git-core +svn fails with MacPort

Tags: git, svn, installation, macports

I tried several tricks, clean all, and no luck. Any tips?

```
sudo port install git-core +svn +doc

--->  Computing dependencies for git-core
--->  Building db46
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix" && /usr/bin/make -j2 all " returned error 2

Command output: /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -c -O2 -arch x86_64  -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -c -I. -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -O2 -arch x86_64  ../dist/../common/util_sig.c
 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -c -O2 -arch x86_64 -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/db_dump185.o
 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -c -I. -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -O2 -arch x86_64 ../dist/../common/util_sig.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/util_sig.o
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c: In function 'main':
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:211: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:213: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:228: error: 'DB' has no member named 'seq'
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:228: error: 'R_NEXT' undeclared (first use in this function)
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:228: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:228: error: for each function it appears in.)
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:233: error: 'DB' has no member named 'seq'
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c: In function 'db_hash':
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:261: error: 'DB' has no member named 'internal'
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:263: error: 'DB' has no member named 'internal'
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c: In function 'db_btree':
../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:288: error: 'DB' has no member named 'internal'
make: *** [db_dump185.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -c -I. -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -O2 -arch x86_64 ../dist/../common/util_sig.c -o util_sig.o >/dev/null 2>&1


Error: The following dependencies failed to build: p5-svn-simple subversion-perlbindings apr-util db46 cyrus-sasl2 gettext neon serf subversion p5-term-readkey rsync popt
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

Answer (score 2):

It has been suggested (e.g. [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/21649) and [here](http://old.nabble.com/-MacPorts---22062%3a-db46-build-error-td25892880.html)) that moving aside /usr/local and then doing port clean db46 and then installing will fix things.

This didn't work for me.  However, this did:

```
sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.hold
# using -f to ignore dependencies, since we're about to re-install it
sudo port -f uninstall db46
sudo port clean db46
# See note below, you may actually want to install something different
# (like your git-core install)
sudo port install db46
sudo mv /usr/local.hold /usr/local
```

I don't actually know if the /usr/local steps were relevant in my case -- I suspect not, as I don't have db46 installed there.  I think it was just that a previous version of db46 was causing problems.

This strikes me as being a bug in db46 and/or its port definition or configure script or something, which causes it to reference a header file that's installed on the system somewhere instead of a version of the same header file from the build tree.  I haven't dug into it to find out, though.

Also note: I was actually building this for another port, and it wanted the +universal variant (not sure why, but whatever) -- so my port install step above was kinda useless, because when I did a port install on the other package I wanted, it re-did it with +universal, and *had the same problem again*!  Sigh.  Still, doing a `sudo port -f uninstall db46` and `sudo port clean db46` again and then doing my main install made everything work.

Comment: That seems thorough, but it's really long ago I posted this question I recall I went another path, and I don't wanna miss it up. Thanks for sharing it for everybody else (maybe me in the future) though

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, hopefully someone else will find it useful.  This page was the top hit for some search or other that I did, so I figured I'd add the answer, once I figured it out.  ;)  Glad you found something else in the mean time.

Answer (score -2):

Did you upgrade to SNOW LEOPARD (or any other Mac OS X version) recently?

Follow [this](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) guide and your problems will go away.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I've gone through the dark days of Snow Leopard before and hoped they're over. I tried nevertheless what you suggested again and same thing :(

Comment: Wow, uninstall everything and then cherry-pick stuff to re-install, huh?  Sounds like something that might be a good idea now and again, but which is also pretty disruptive.  And it doesn't necessarily actually solve this problem (per comment from the OP), so, -1 for the "your problems will go away" statement.